# Convert open Google Doc to HTML

Tags: html, google-docs-api

Ok, I give in, spun myself in a web of google docs/drive APIs, could do with an escape knife.

I'm trying to add an app script that will let me export Google docs to an external knowledge centre (Zendesk). To import into Zendesk through their API, I need to convert the document to HTML. 
While it's very simple to get a pdf of your current doc

`DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs('application/pdf')`

it doesn't let you change the content type to text/html.

Anyone know a different route to take?

I've tried going down the route of

`file['exportLists']['text/html']`

but I can't seem to get access to the file while you're editing it.

Any help or pointers much appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to get a pdf of the doc. Directly convert Google text-only Document to HTML. To see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948900/how-to-convert-a-simple-google-text-only-document-to-html-via-google-apps-script